# Send file trough FTP using command line without interactive mode

Tags: linux, ftp, command-line-interface

I want to automate sending of a file through FTP using command line (on Linux). By this I mean that I want to send a file straight from the command line, without any interactive mode. I want to pass all parameters from the command line (it is on a local network for private purposes, so having password on the command line is fine for me). I know what file I want to send, and where I want to store it. My google-fu has failed me so far, because all guides concerning "command line ftp" are actually entering the interactive text interface, which is not what I want.

So how do I send a file through FTP if I do not want to enter the interactive mode and want to pass all parameters on command line?

Comment: What OS?  What FTP program?

Comment: @TimBrigham: The [tag:linux] tag indicates the OS, and since it's easy to install additional tools on any Linux....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible, install `ncftp` and use `ncftpput` and `ncftpget` commands for scripting uploading and downloading files.

`lftp` has also `-c` (reads FTP commands from command line parameters) and `-f` (reads FTP commands from a text file) options which can help you automating your FTP sessions.

If you somehow truly have to use the archaic `ftp` command, you can use `expect` (or, `autoexpect`).

Comment: Thanks, `ncftpput -u user -p pass host remote-dir local-file` works great.

Comment: Great. Have a nice weekend! :)

Answer (score 0):

lftp?

```
$ yum info lftp
Loaded plugins: priorities, ps
Available Packages
Name        : lftp
Arch        : i686
Version     : 4.0.9
Release     : 1.el6
Size        : 735 k
Repo        : base
Summary     : A sophisticated file transfer program
URL         : http://lftp.yar.ru/
License     : GPLv3+
Description : LFTP is a sophisticated ftp/http file transfer program. Like bash, it has job
            : control and uses the readline library for input. It has bookmarks, built-in
            : mirroring, and can transfer several files in parallel. It is designed with
            : reliability in mind.
```

The man page is here: http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html

Answer (score 0):

Install `ncftp` and use the utitilies `ncftpput` and `ncftpget`.

Comment: Huh. For some reason, I had thought ncftp had been deprecated in favor of lftp.